# Issues in json_encode

Tags: php, json

I have this array:

```
$array = [
  "stored_fields" => ["id"], 
  "match_all" => []
];
```

I want:

```
{"stored_fields":["id"],"match_all":{}}
```

But, When I call:

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

I got:

```
{"stored_fields":["id"],"match_all":[]}
```

If I use:

```
echo json_encode($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

I got:

```
{"stored_fields":{"0":"id"},"match_all":{}}
```

What I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a better way, but you can just force an object:

```
$array = [
  "stored_fields" => ["id"], 
  "match_all" => (object)[]
];
```

You could also use `(object)null`.  Anything else will result in `{"scalar":someting}`.  Another option is `new stdClass`.